# No connection string named 'BddContext' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to use the localdb with asp mvc
I installed EF 6.0 from my visual studio 2013 (with nuget)

### First in my project i add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" :

```
using OCR_Restaurant.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace OCR_Restaurant
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;

    public class BddContext : DbContext
    {
        public BddContext()
            : base("name=BddContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Sondage> Sondages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Resto> Restos { get; set; }
}
```

### Then my Interface :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OCR_Restaurant.Models
{
    interface IDal: IDisposable
    {
        void CreerRestaurant(string nom, string telephone);
        List<Resto> ObtientTousLesRestaurants();
    }
}
```

### And my Dal :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OCR_Restaurant.Models
{
    public class Dal:IDal
    {
        private BddContext bdd;

        public Dal()
        {
            bdd = new BddContext();
        }

        public List<Resto> ObtientTousLesRestaurants()
        {
            return bdd.Restos.ToList();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            bdd.Dispose();
        }

        public void CreerRestaurant(string nom, string telephone)
        {
            Resto resto = new Resto { Id = 1, Nom = nom, Telephone = telephone };
            bdd.Restos.Add(resto);
        }
    }
}
```

### In my Web.config :

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BddContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=OCR_Restaurant.BddContext;integrated security=TRUE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

### This is my Test class :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Data.Entity;
using OCR_Restaurant.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace OCR_Restaurant.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class DalTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CreerRestaurant_AvecUnNouveauRestaurant_ObtientTousLesRestaurantsRenvoitBienLeRestaurant()
        {
            using (Dal dal = new Dal())
            {
                dal.CreerRestaurant("La bonne fourchette", "01 02 03 04 05");
                List<Resto> restos = dal.ObtientTousLesRestaurants();

                Assert.IsNotNull(restos);
                Assert.AreEqual(1, restos.Count);
                Assert.AreEqual("La bonne fourchette", restos[0].Nom);
                Assert.AreEqual("01 02 03 04 05", restos[0].Telephone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the "test", i have this message :
"No connection string named 'BddContext' could be found in the application config file"

I think everything is good, but maybe something wrong ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The **test** is the one running the code. When it looks for a connectionstring, it looks in it's own project, not in your MVC project.

The fast and easy solution would be to add that **connection string** to your test project's app.config file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a separate test project that contains your test class (DalTests). If you ensure the test project's app.config has the same BddContext connection string entry, the error should not occur, because the test project looks in its own config file, not that of the mvc project or any other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

With your indications i found the solution :

- Right clic testproject and add item named "application config file"
- In the testprject : i must install entity framework too

Then visual studio generate a good app.config.
Inside this file add the connectionstring.